# How to use raspberry pi as a multi peripheral device

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bleno

I am using Bleno package in raspberry pi and making it a peripheral device when I run nodejs application I can connect from the mobile app. My main problem is I cannot use Pi as it works like many peripheral devices, because it's not possible to buy too many Pis to make peripherals, So Is it possible?

Comment: You should probably show some code. Also, is your question "is it possible with Bleno" or "is it possible in general"? Because for the latter: yes, of course your RPi could _somehow_ publish multiple BLE services.

Comment: Wasn't finding any solutions that's why generally asking Is it possible, then can you please tell me how one raspberry pi can advertise using multiple peripheral device names?

Comment: If you need each peripheral to have their own address, you'll also need multiple Bluetooth adapters. If it's okay to just publish multiple services with the same address, `bleno.setServices()`...